# Stopping GP script from adding temporary data to Table of Contents?

Tags: arcpy, arcgis-10.1, python-addin, wxpython

I have a script that does a series of calculations, producing temporary data along the way. However, at each step of the script, data is added to the TOC and then removed when I call the arcpy.Delete_management function on the data. Before my script reaches the delete function, the temporary data that I've calculated is shown in the TOC. Is there a way to explicitly specify these datasets as temporary, or freeze the TOC during script processing. Example below:

```python
class StationTypology:

    def __init__(self, areaName, bufferDistance):
        self.areaName = areaName
        self.bufferDistance = bufferDistance

    def BusinessDensity(self):
        try:
            # Make a temporary table in memory based on query of feature class
            query = ("""\"AreaName\" = '""" + self.areaName + """' AND
                     \"BufferDistance\" = """ + str(self.bufferDistance) + """ AND
                     \"UseType\" = 'Business'""")

            arcpy.MakeTableView_management("LANDUSE",
                                           "business",
                                           query)

            # Calculate the sum of floor space, from above table
            arcpy.Statistics_analysis("business",
                                      "in_memory\\businessStatistics",
                                      [["FloorArea", "SUM"]])

            # Use SearchCursor to access table records and store rows in a variable
            rows = arcpy.SearchCursor("in_memory\\businessStatistics",
                                      "",
                                      "",
                                      "SUM_FloorArea",
                                      "")

            # Table has one row; access with iteration, grab value of SUM_FloorArea
            for row in rows:
                businessDensity = row.SUM_FloorArea

            del rows  # Housekeeping
            arcpy.Delete_management("business")  # Housekeeping
            arcpy.Delete_management("in_memory\\businessStatistics")  # Housekeeping

            return businessDensity

        except:
            try:
                del rows  # Housekeeping
                arcpy.Delete_management("business")  # Housekeeping
                arcpy.Delete_management("in_memory\\businessStatistics")  # Housekeeping
            except:
                pass
```

I am not sure if it matters, but the script is being called from a wxPython GUI launched inside of ArcGIS as a Python Add-In. The GUI contains a button with an event that triggers the above script.

Comment: If you run the script from outside of ArcMap(IDLE shell), or as a script tool, temporary layers aren't added to the map.

Comment: I understand, but I want the scripts to be executed inside my Python Add-In GUI through user events (buttons).

Answer (score 1, accepted):

See the answer on the [Esri forums](https://community.esri.com/thread/54311). Set `arcpy.env.addOutputsToMap` to `False` at the beginning, then back to `True` when you're done.

Comment: Modify the same options in .NET ArcObjects:

http://resources.arcgis.com/en/help/arcobjects-net/componenthelp/#/AddOutputsToMap_Property/002n00000127000000/

[C#]
public bool AddOutputsToMap {get; set;}
Though probably fairly obvious based on the ArcPy answer, I had failed to make the connection.

Comment: This is a link only answer and the link now only goes to a [Discussions Lobby](https://community.esri.com/community/discussions-lobby) page.